# uglify.js, internet explorer 9 error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

please help

don't know what's this but seems **uglify.js source maps proceed with IE9 error**

it looks like

```
 User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
 Timestamp: Tue, 23 Apr 2013 07:29:26 UTC
 Message: Expected ';'
 Line: 25
 Char: 28
 Code: 0
 URI: http://[site address is hidden by me]:[port is hidden by me]/[long hash is also hidden by me].min.js
```

Did anyone see smth like this before?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in comment `//@ sourceMapUrl`

more details on IE-only conditional comments here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3091907/2117550